# psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: python, psycopg2, geodjango

I recently started following the Geodjango tutorials on the Django documentation. I have installed all I need: PostgreSQL, PostGIS, psycopg2, GDAL. My python version is 3.7.0 and django version is 2.1

Anytime I run py manage.py makemigrations I get this error[image]

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your `settings.py` you are setting the database `PASSWORD`, not `PASS` as is expected by default. That's what threw me!